# Can PIL/ImageDraw shift previous images and/or insert new ones in their place?

Tags: python, image, graphics, python-imaging-library, shapes

I'm guessing this is better for a more advanced library (even something like Pygame), but I'm still looking at all the options. Here's an example of what I need to able to with graphic images after creating them. It's my way of organizing my Hierarchy-Based system (organizing macro-to-micro). Each tab represents a different entity, and each color/size tab is obviously a different Rank. For example:

[Original input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98Zh.png)

So I need to  have a way for new tabs to be inserted spontaneously (like inserting rows in Excel, which isn't much easier on Python either). Case in point: something is part of a Supercluster but still contains many Clusters, so it has to be inserted between the two like this:

[Modified Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGJcD.png)

This means (again, like Excel) that whenever a new line is entered, all the tabs (really ImageDraw shapes) below it have to shift down–and there could be hundreds. So is there a way to code this in and make it easy? Or is this not within the realm of this  library?

I've researched PIL/ImageDraw...you can resize images, etc., but I don't see anything about shifting them.

Comment: Usually it would be easiest just to redraw the whole thing instead of trying to insert.

Comment: So the coordinates would all have to be changed for the ones below it. Could that be done with an for loop or if-else loop, instructing it to lower the coordinates for a given range of the tabs?

Comment: A for loop would be perfect, adjust the coordinates for every loop iteration.

Comment: Ok thanks. Eventually I'd like to create a software so people can just click on the tab and add sublevels instantly (more a Pygame thing), but this seems like a good step in transitioning, allowing the system to be updated quickly with code.

Comment: I agree with @MarkRansom - it is probably simplest to just redraw the entire image. You ***could*** hold each of the bars each drawn on its own piece of canvas in a list and sort the list and then concatenate the bars into a stack, but it's just as simple and fast to redraw the whole lot when the list changes.

Comment: So Mark, do you agree that a for loop would accomplish this?